# How to execute a program within python and allow the user to interact with it?

Tags: python, windows

Is it possible to execute a program within python, e.g. an interactive command, SSH, telnet, etc, and then release the control to the user so he is free to interact with the program. The control is returned to python after the program terminates?

```
os.system("ssh 3.4.5.6");
# user interact with the command until it terminates
print("All Done")
```

(Edit: sorry, I gave a bad example, the command I want to run is python and it didn't work for me. I will post a diff question)

Comment: If you don't need feedback from the program, you could open a new process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to execute a program within python and then release the control to the user, you will have to use `os.system("your command")` to run command and if that command requires interaction you will be able to do so on the cmd window.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is Possible to execute python program and let user to interact with it by **os.system(command)** .

Comment: Welcome to SO! @naqviO7, I do not see the difference between your answer and the previous answer. Can you please elaborate in your answer?